# Directly accessing a report in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, reporting, lightning-experience, analytics

So in Salesforce Classic I'm able to directly download my reports as CSV by going to the following link:
https://myorg.my.salesforce.com/?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv

But in Lightning Experience, this doesn't work any more!

Is there a way to directly access the CSV export link in Lightning Experience?

Comment: Hi taralex, did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same problem and believe it is related to an intercepting animation that has been introduced in SF Lightning (currently fireworks '16), so when accessing the URL programtically it fails due to the webrequest returning the intercepting page rather than the CSV.

Comment: No, haven't figured it out yet, not sure it's even possible... No wonder no one wants to switch to lightning with quirks like this.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem. Try appending the `isdtp=p1`parameter to your URL:

> https://myorg.my.salesforce.com/?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv&isdtp=p1

Comment: Works. This should be the accepted answer. :)